# Inno Setup URLDownloadToCacheFile

Tags: inno-setup

Any time i try to compile this code, a get an error msg -> Type mismatch. Why?

The first variant is called with the same "nil" and the compiler has no problem with it, but with the last?

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp
AppVerName=MyApp
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
DefaultGroupName=MyApp
OutputDir=.

[Code]
function URLDownloadToCacheFile(const lpUnkcaller: variant; const szURL: PAnsiChar; var szFileName: PAnsiChar; const cchFileName: DWORD; const dwReserved: DWORD; IBindStatusCallback: variant): HRESULT; external 'URLDownloadToFileW@Urlmon.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  szFileName, szURL : PAnsiChar;
  ErrorCode : HRESULT;
  MAX_PATH : DWORD;
begin
  szURL := 'http://fs2.directupload.net/images/user/150607/x3sugvzy.jpg';
  MAX_PATH := 512;
  SetLength(szFileName, MAX_PATH + 1);
  ErrorCode := URLDownloadToCacheFile(null, szURL, szFileName, MAX_PATH, 0, null);
end;
```

changed code that way:

```
[Setup]
AppName=MyApp
AppVerName=MyApp
DefaultDirName={pf}\MyApp
DefaultGroupName=MyApp
OutputDir=.

[Code]
function URLDownloadToCacheFile(const lpUnkcaller: variant; const szURL: AnsiString; var szFileName: String; const cchFileName: DWORD; const dwReserved: DWORD; IBindStatusCallback: variant): HRESULT; external 'URLDownloadToFileW@Urlmon.dll stdcall';

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
    szFileName : String;
    szURL : AnsiString;
    ErrorCode : HRESULT;
    MAX_PATH : DWORD;
begin
    szURL := 'http://fs2.directupload.net/images/user/150607/x3sugvzy.jpg';
    MAX_PATH := 512;
    SetLength(szFileName, 513);
    ErrorCode := URLDownloadToCacheFile(null, szURL, szFileName, MAX_PATH, 0, null);
    MsgBox(szFileName,mbConfirmation, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: Null value for `Variant` type is `NULL`, not `nil`.

Comment: P.S. the `szFileName` is of type `LPTSTR` and you are using Unicode Inno Setup (because of `PAnsiChar` type).

Comment: thx for this super fast answer. will modify this.

Comment: i changed nil -> null .. compiler works now.

Comment: For `LPCSTR` parameters you can use `AnsiString` in Unicode Inno Setup, or `string` in ANSI Inno Setup. For `LPTSTR` it can be `string` in Unicode IS, or `WideString` in ANSI IS if you are using it in context of a Unicode function variant (which is your case). P.S. do not use answer posts for asking new questions, please. If you have a new question, ask it separately (or, if it's an update to your current one, edit it, please).

Comment: sorry. first time of use of this system. will not happen again.

Comment: No worries ;-) The real problem is that MSDN is wrong here. If you check the header file (I'm looking at the header from SDK 8.1), you will see that the `szURL` parameter is actually of type `LPCTSTR`, not `LPCSTR`. So it's ANSI type for ANSI variant and Unicode for Unicode variant.

Comment: And all that `Variant` stuff will fail as well I guess...

Comment: it fails, yes .... access violation ... but thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original problem was that you were passing `nil` to a parameter of type `Variant`. Null value for the `Variant` type is `NULL` in Pascal Script.

But, your prototype needs to be changed. You need to use Unicode data types when you are using Unicode variant of a function, so you cannot use `PAnsiChar` types there. The next problem is with the `Variant` types you used for interface type parameters. That won't work. You can use `IUnknown` types there, because the `lpUnkcaller` parameter is of a pointer to this type and `pBSC` is of type `IBindStatusCallback` which from `IUnknown` inherits. The last problem is that MSDN is wrong here. The `szURL` is according to the header files of type `LPCTSTR`, not `LPCSTR`. The Unicode variant prototype looks like this in SDK 8.1 urlmon.h header file (formatted and commented by me):

```c
STDAPI URLDownloadToCacheFileW(
    _In_opt_ LPUNKNOWN,
    _In_ LPCWSTR, // <- this is wrong on MSDN; this type would have to be LPCSTR here
    _Out_writes_(cchFileName) LPWSTR,
    DWORD cchFileName,
    DWORD,
    _In_opt_ LPBINDSTATUSCALLBACK
);
```

So, your script might be written like this (it should support also ANSI version of Inno Setup, but I haven't tested it there):

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
const
  MAX_PATH = 260;
  S_OK = $00000000;

#ifdef UNICODE
  #define AW "W"
#else
  #define AW "A"
#endif

function URLDownloadToCacheFile(lpUnkcaller: IUnknown; szURL: string; szFileName: string;
  cchFileName: DWORD; dwReserved: DWORD; pBSC: IUnknown): HRESULT;
  external 'URLDownloadToCacheFile{#AW}@urlmon.dll stdcall';

function TryDownloadToCache(const URL: string; out FileName: string): Boolean;
begin
  SetLength(FileName, MAX_PATH);
  Result := URLDownloadToCacheFile(nil, URL, FileName, Length(FileName), 0, nil) = S_OK;
end;

function InitializeSetup: Boolean;
var
  FileName: string;
  ErrorCode: Integer;
begin
  Result := True;

  if TryDownloadToCache('http://i.imgur.com/wKCsei6.png', FileName) then
    ShellExec('', FileName, '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode)
  else
    MsgBox('Downloading failed.', mbError, MB_OK);
end;
```

Comment: thx for your fix, the solution and your detailed reply. i found this  (http://www.delphipraxis.net/47-datei-downloaden-mit-fortschrittsanzeige.html).
my intention was to download as a background process (with callback for trace), but can´t make it work.